# how to Insert update delete mysql database from datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

i want to insert update and delete mysql database using datagridview but i have not found any tutorial for that, some tutorial are found about Ms sql , but i want it in mysql please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far, show some attempt and we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this approach

```
 this.id = string.Empty;
 using (MySqlConnection mysqlConn = new MySqlConnection(this.connString))
 {
   string mysqlQuery = @"SELECT * from Student";
   using (MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, this.connString))
     {
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       ad.Fill(ds);
       dgvStudentDelete.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     }
 }
```

but no idea about how to directly do it from datagridview